# Is there an interface wrapper around the Task Parallel Library so that I can swap it out for unit testing?

Tags: .net, multithreading, unit-testing, task-parallel-library

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362734/unit-testing-concurrent-software-what-do-you-do) a while ago.  I now know it is a Bad Idea and that encapsulating the scheduling and running of tasks should be abstracted so that one can pass in a synchronous  scheduler from the unit tests.

I've currently got code that uses the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) (TPL) and I'd like to inject something like `ITaskScheduler` into my types to extract out responsibility of scheduling and enable me to pass in a synchronous alternative in my tests.

Does such a thing exist?  I'm looking for something that wraps `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `Task.ContinueWith`.  I don't suppose it's not too much work to roll my own, but I'm sure there's lots of little *gotchas* and I don't really want to spend time doing it if there's one already available.

Comment: I don't think that there could by any gotchas as far as you put the Task API straight behind an interface. Using that interface shouldn't be much different to using the API directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substituting the `Task` class is hard, even if you inherit a new class from `Task`: since `TaskScheduler` and `TaskFactory` aren't generic on `Task` it will not help much at all.

A better approach in my experience is to use your own `TaskScheduler` class (inherited from `TaskScheduler`).  You can pass it into a `TaskFactory` constructor and then use that `TaskFactory` throughout.

Now for testing you can use a different `TaskScheduler` with varying degrees of parallelism (down to 1 thread if you want) and you can add extra logging to your `TaskScheduler` class to log each task as it starts and finishes.

Answer (score 2):

You could define such an interface and wrap the actual library classes inside a facade that implements the interface. For testing, swap your Facade against a mock object.